# OData get resource by ID and name

Tags: asp.net-web-api, odata

I have this code sample that I'm trying to make the 3rd Get method to work, and also have `$expand` to work as explained below.

If I ONLY have the methods `Get()` and `Get([FromODataUri] int key)`, I can call them both with these respective routes `/odata/Products` and `/odata/Products(1)?$expand=Vendor`.
However, I get the below problems when I make the following changes.

1. If I only change the parameter name `key` to `id` or anything else in method `Get([FromODataUri] int key)`, then the method is no longer called. The route call of `/odata/Products(1)` goes to the `Get()` method which always returns all collection.
2. If I put the parameter name back to `key`, but change the method to something else e.g. `GetByKey([FromODataUri] int key)`, then the same problem above happens again.
3. Also, if I call with `/odata/Products?key=1?$expand=Vendor`, the call goes to `GetByKey([FromODataUri] int key)`, but I don't get the Vendor expanded.
4. And adding the 3rd method below `GetByName([FromODataUri] string name)`, I get "error 404 not found" when called with this route, `/odata/Products('Product 1')`. And if called with `/odata/Products?name='Product 1'` or `/odata/Products?name='Product 1'$expand=Vendor`, then the `Get()` method is triggered and again Vendor doesn't get expanded.

I would appreciate your input on this.

```
public static class WebApiConfig
{
    public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
    {
        // Web API configuration and services

        // Web API routes
        config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "DefaultApi",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
        );

        ODataModelBuilder builder = new ODataConventionModelBuilder();
        builder.EntitySet<Product    ("Products");
        config.MapODataServiceRoute("ODataRoute", "odata", builder.GetEdmModel());

    }
}

public class ProductsController : ODataController
{
    #region 

    ProductsContext db = new ProductsContext();
    private bool ProductExists(int key)
    {
        return db.Products.Any(p =     p.Id == key);
    }
    protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        db.Dispose();
        base.Dispose(disposing);
    }

    #endregion

    [HttpGet]
    [EnableQuery]
    public IQueryable<Product     Get()
    {
        return db.Products.AsQueryable();
    }

    [HttpGet]
    [EnableQuery]
    public SingleResult<Product     Get([FromODataUri] int key)
    {
        IQueryable<Product     result = db.Products.Where(p =     p.Id == key).AsQueryable();
        return SingleResult.Create(result);
    }

    [HttpGet]
    [EnableQuery]
    public SingleResult<Product     GetByName([FromODataUri] string name)
    {
        IQueryable<Product     result = db.Products.Where(p =     p.Name == name).AsQueryable();
        return SingleResult.Create(result);
    }
}

public class Product
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    public decimal Price { get; set; }

    public string Category { get; set; }

    public Vendor Vendor { get; set; }

}

public class Vendor
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }

}

public class ProductsContext : IDisposable
{
    public ICollection<Product     Products = new List<Product    ()
    {
        new Product()
        {
            Category = "A",
            Id = 1,
            Name = "Product 1",
            Price = 10,
            Vendor = new Vendor()
            {
                Id = 1,
                Name = "Vendor 1"
            }
        },

        new Product()
        {
            Category = "A",
            Id = 2,
            Name = "Product 2",
            Price = 15,
            Vendor = new Vendor()
            {
                Id = 1,
                Name = "Vendor 1"
            }
        },

        new Product()
        {
            Category = "B",
            Id = 3,
            Name = "Product 3",
            Price = 10,
            Vendor = new Vendor()
            {
                Id = 2,
                Name = "Vendor 2"
            }
        },
    };

    public void Dispose()
    {

    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Your code is using the [built-in routing conventions](http://odata.github.io/WebApi/#03-02-built-in-routing-conventions) of the ASP.NET implementation of OData, and the issues you are having are a result of those conventions.

1. In the URI path `/odata/Products(1)`, the `(1)` part is called a key segment. By convention, `key` is the name of the parameter used to hold the value of the key segment. Unfortunately, this does not match the convention of naming the key properties of your models as `Id`. You can override this routing convention by using [attribute routing](http://odata.github.io/WebApi/#03-03-attrribute-routing), but it is not worth the effort in my opinion.
2. The routing convention is [expecting](https://github.com/OData/WebApi/blob/master/OData/src/System.Web.OData/OData/Routing/Conventions/EntityRoutingConvention.cs#L65) a method named `GetProduct` or just `Get`. Again, you can override the conventional behavior by using `ODataRouteAttribute`.
3. The proper URI for retrieving a member of the Products entity set is `/odata/Products(id)`. In my test environment, `GET /odata/Products?key=1&$expand=Vendor` is not routed to `GetByKey`. Rather, it is routed to the parameterless `Get` method, as it should be according to the routing conventions (because there is no key segment in the request URI).
4. If the `Name` property of the Product entity is an alternate key, then you can take advantage of the [alternate key support](http://odata.github.io/WebApi/#04-17-Alternate-Key) in ASP.NET OData. You can retrieve Products by name as follows: `GET /odata/Products(Name='name')`. See [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35802999/1257889) to a previous question for a description of how to implement alternate keys in your controller.

Comment: Appreciate your input it's great!

I looked into the alternate key and didn't like the fact to have to write code to define each model and its keys/properties etc... so, what I ended up doing is just adding the [Key] attribute to the Name property in my view model.

Comment: If my post helped, please consider upvoting or accepting it as the answer.

Comment: I will gladly once it lets me (gain my 15 reputations).

Answer (score 2):

For, #1, #2, #4 don't work because the action names or parameters don't follow up Web API OData routing convention. Conventions are a set of default [rules](http://odata.github.io/WebApi/#03-02-built-in-routing-conventions) that the developer should follow up to make sure Web API OData can route the request to correct method in the controller.

For #3, because it uses the Web API routes, that's

> api/{controller}/{action}/{id}

Not use the Web API OData routing.

Hope the material [here](http://odata.github.io/WebApi/#03-01-routing-abstract) can help you understanding the routing in Web API OData. Thanks.

Comment: Problem #3 has nothing to do with the Web API routes. Those routes are prefixed with `/api`, while the OData routes are prefixed with `/odata`.

Comment: Ok. Did you miss the "&" before $expand:

/odata/Products?key=1&$expand=Vendor

However, the correct request Uri should be:

~/odata/Products(1)?$expand=Vendor

Comment: Thanks guys, and yes Sam I did forget the '&' thanks for catching that up. And you're right about the correct URI of /odata/Products(1)?$expand=Vendor.